# How to run all the test functions under a specific module?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Say there is a module with multiple tests underneath, such as the following. How do you run all the tests under this module but not other modules?

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod cool_tests {
   #[test]
   fn first_test() {
      // Test Code
   }

   #[test]
   fn second_test() {
      // Test Code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply run all the tests under the module as follows:

```
cargo test cool_tests::
```

If you want to filter based on name, say all that start with 'first,' you can run the tests as follows:

```
cargo test cool_tests::first
```

Comment: This doesn't run my test...

Comment: nvm my issue was that I was adding `#[cfg(tests)]` rather than `#[cfg(test)]` 